# Excuse me, everyone. I built Setup.exe from Visual Studio 2019. but I try installation to another PC/Laptop it not working

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio

I create window application and built program as .EXE then I test installation on laptops. some laptop can complete installation and can launch program.exe after installation (they has Visual Studio 2019). In the other hand some laptop hasn't Visual Studio. They can installation this program setup.exe. After that Desktop show Icon of program and on Tap START show my program, when I double click for open program. It's not response anything. How I can do for launch my Program setup.EXE for every PC/Laptop without install Visual Studio?

Detail:

I use .NET 4.8

create program for support Windows 32bit

Comment: Does your installation setup has all the required library to run the executable file?

Comment: Have you checked if all the laptops have .NET 4.8?

Comment: Exe itself is not sufficient... you need to have all the necessary dll files to go with it, in the same directory

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure the PC/Laptop you use to install your program has a **.net framework installed.**
You can use this [link](https://dotnet.microsoft.com/download/dotnet-framework) to install .net framework

Comment: Yes sir @Andrei, I installed .NET 4.8 in my PC and I installed .NET4.8 (run time) in to another PC

Comment: @VrizZhang did you publish first your application?

Comment: Yes sir. This is my first time.

Comment: That's fine, just publish first the application, then install .net framework on the unit you're going to transfer, then install, it should be working just fine unless your application has a database.